# SQL Performance: Multiple Binds or Bind to One SQL Variable for Re-use?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, spring

My question is related to determining how to get the best SQL performance out of my queries.
Currently, I'm connecting to SQL Server using a Java Spring application. In my app, I do queries that join multiple tables and bind values to the query.

Here's an example of what one of these queries looks like. The key to note for my question is that all the bound variables are the same value.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA data
LEFT OUTER JOIN join1 ON data.id1=join1.id and join1.id2=?
LEFT OUTER JOIN join2 ON data.id2=join2.id and join2.id2=?
LEFT OUTER JOIN join3 ON data.id3=join3.id and join3.id2=?
```

What I was thinking might be better would be to bind that value to a SQL parameter instead. So the revised query might look like this:

```
DECLARE @bind_value varchar
SET @bind_value=?    
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA data
LEFT OUTER JOIN join1 ON data.id1=join1.id and join1.id2=@bind_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN join2 ON data.id2=join2.id and join2.id2=@bind_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN join3 ON data.id3=join3.id and join3.id2=@bind_value
```

Does this help or hurt performance? Or is there a better way to write the query altogether?
Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For example, I have two equal queries:***

```
--1

DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = '20130101'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Absence a
LEFT JOIN dbo.ScheduleDetail sd ON a.AbsenceCode = sd.AbsenceCode 
    AND sd.DateOut = @Date

--2

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Absence a
LEFT JOIN dbo.ScheduleDetail sd ON a.AbsenceCode = sd.AbsenceCode 
    AND sd.DateOut = '20130101'
```

***Execution plan in SSMS:***

[image: SSMS]

***Сomparison for two queries:***

[image: dbForge Profiler]

[image: dbForge Query Profiler]

Comment: So, you will not see any difference between these queries.

Comment: Hmm, so based on those results from your comparison, the only difference at all is the amount of memory utilized. The execution time appears to have been identical. This is good information. Thank you!